# javascript object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to serialize a javascript object but with a particular form(I think it has to be a method).
Example:

```
var media = new Object();
media.url = "localhost";
media.foo = "asd"

var data=new Object();
data.title = "myTitle";
data.description = "myDescription";
data.media.push(media);
```

I need to serialize data this way:

> "title=myTitle&description=myDescription&media[0].url=localhost&media[0].foo=asd"

The important thing is the way the array is written.

Comment: Is this being used with a jQuery AJAX function? If you give it an object as the `data:` option, it will serialize for you.

Comment: Tip: `new Object == {}`

Comment: You forgot to initialize `data.media`

Comment: @Bergi thats not important

Comment: Don't use `new Object`.  Declare it using `{}`.  `var data = {title: "mytitle", media: [ {url: "localhost"} ]};`.

Comment: `media[0].url` isn't the right format.  It'd really be `media[0][url]` when serialized.  If you use jQuery, there is `$.param`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the data will be used in post. And yes, I'm giving it to the data

Comment: @Federico: In that case, you don't need to serialize it, just do `$.ajax({url: 'example.com', data: data});`.

Comment: I have to put it in the way I wrote

Comment: @Federico: Why does it need to be in *that* format?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Why do you claim that to be "*not the right format*"? It's the format the OP requested, and if `$.param` doesn't conform with that you cannot use it…

Comment: $.param combined with decodeURIComponent() works like a charm.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17351537/788509

Comment: @Bergi: I assumed he was sending that data via GET or POST and that was a query string.  So, I assumed he typed the format incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to serialize an object into a list (string) of parameters, have a look:

[How to serialize an Object into a list of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566456/how-to-serialize-a-object-into-a-list-of-parameters)

One example is a method such as the below:

```
var str = "";
for (var key in obj) {
   if (str != "") {
       str += "&";
   }
   str += key + "=" + obj[key];
}
```

You can modify it to suit the style you need.

Comment: In addition to handling recursive objects, you need to call `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Thanks, I made something like your response

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Convert a JSON object's keys into dot notation paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597662/convert-a-json-objects-keys-into-dot-notation-paths) and [Convert complex JavaScript object to dot notation object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218745/convert-complex-json-object-to-dot-notation-json-object). You can easily adapt those to handle your array keys special:

```
function transform(obj) {
    var result = {};
    recurse(obj, "");
    return result;
    function recurse(o, name) {
        if (Object(o) !== o)
            result[name] = o;
        else if (Array.isArray(o))
            for (var i=0; i<o.length; i++)
                recurse(o[i], name+"["+i+"]");
        else // if plain object?
            for (var p in o)
                recurse(o[p], name?name+"."+p:p);
    }
}
```

You can then apply [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) on the result to get the URL encoding etc:

```
$.param(transform(data))
```

(or just pass it into the data parameter of `$.ajax`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I need to change. Thought it was easier but when looking at the result I saw that it was not so straight forward. If you're using jquery though you can simply do it like this:

```
var media = new Object();
media.url = "localhost";
media.foo = "asd"

var data=new Object();
data.title = "myTitle";
data.description = "myDescription";
data.media = []; // you forgot this...
data.media.push(media);

var data = $.param(data));
```

Comment: Wasn't asked for as far as I can see.

Comment: something like this, but with support for arrays

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery.param to do this:

```
$.param({a:'2', b: 1.2, c: "hello world"})// -> a=2&b=1.2&c=hello+world

EDIT
```

What I was missing above is the array support sorry bout that.

For this you'll need to decodeURIComponent()

```
var media = new Object();
media.url = "localhost";
media.foo = "asd"

var data=new Object();
data.title = "myTitle";
data.description = "myDescription";
data.media = [];
data.media.push(media);
alert(decodeURIComponent($.param(data)));
```

Output:

title=myTitle&description=myDescription&media[0][url]=localhost&media[0][foo]=asd

http://jsfiddle.net/bLu8Q/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides this via [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

```
var params = $.param(data);
console.log(params);
```

Produces:

```
title=myTitle&description=myDescription&media%5B0%5D%5Burl%5D=localhost&media%5B0%5D%5Bfoo%5D=asd
```

As you can see, it handles the nested array and object as you wish (`%5B` and `%5D` are URL encodings for `[` and `]`).

If you're using `$.ajax()` or one of its shortcuts, you don't need to call this explicitly. If you supply the object as the `data` argument or option, jQuery will automatically serialize it using this method.